# Get an error to install mediapipe in python

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

I am trying to install mediapipe==0.9.1.0 package, but got an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

My python version is 3.12.0 and pip version is 23.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mediapipe](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#data) currently supports Python 3.8 - 3.11. There's no support yet for your Python version. To resolve your issue, downgrade to a supported version of Python and then run `python -m pip install mediapipe`.

Note: it is recommended to use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) instead of removing your python 3.12.0.